# Удаление \n из строки

Tags: c#, строки

Это произошло внезапно...
Я уже сталкивался с проблемой, что в строке нужно удалить "\r\n". Это я легко исправил с помощью `sequence = sequence.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");`

Однако, когда я скачал файл со строкой, а не создал его вручную, скопировав содержимое с сайта, то этот фрагмент кода перестала работать. Теперь в строке только "\n". Как это удалить? 
Так тоже не вышло `sequence = sequence.Trim('\n', '\r');`

Comment: есть пример строки?

Comment: Лучше ссылку дам на страницу с этой строкой.https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/588295077?report=fasta

Comment: Справа вверху есть ссылка "send to". При нажатии появиться небольшое окно где надо выбрать пункт 'File' и нажать "Create file". И со скачанным файлом я и работаю. .fasta открывается обычным блокнотом

Comment: Пробовали `sequence = sequence.Replace("\n", string.Empty);` ?

Comment: Пробовал только что. Получилось)

Comment: @tym32167, можете добавить это в ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас вот это `Environment.NewLine` представляет собой последовательность `\r\n`, потому это `sequence = sequence.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");` не будет работать для `\n`

Вот это `sequence = sequence.Trim('\n', '\r');` удаляет символы только в начале и в конце строки, то есть не ваш вариант.

Вам нужно использовать следующее

```
sequence = sequence.Replace("\n", string.Empty);
```